# HTTP 404 error when debugging in Asp.net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I am trying to create a simple user registration process

When I try to run the application I have the error  HTTP 404.
The resource cannot be found.
Requested URL: /Mvc_Web_Project/Views/CreateNewUser/AddUser.cshtml

Solution i found online did not solve the issue

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

      routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "CreateNewUser", action = "AddUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Controller.cs

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using Mvc_Web_Project.Models;

 namespace Mvc_Web_Project.Controllers
 {
   public class CreateNewUserController : Controller
   {
    private SqlConnection con;
    private void connection()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    }

    // GET: CreateNewUser
    public ActionResult AddUser(AddUserModel CreateNewUser)
    {
        //To Prevent firing validation error on first page Load  

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            connection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("AddUser", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", CreateNewUser.Email);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", CreateNewUser.Password);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", CreateNewUser.Type);               
            con.Open();
            int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (i >= 1)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "New User Added Successfully";
            }
        }
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View();
    }
   }
  }
```

cshtml

```
   @model Mvc_Web_Project.Models.AddUserModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create New User";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }

<h2>AddUser</h2>

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend> AddUserModel</legend>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save details" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
 }
```

Comment: When you run the application, which file do you have open in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Kirk These file are open in Visual Studio (AddUser.cshtml, RouteConfig.cs,  CreateNewuserController.cs, AddUserModel.cs)

Comment: Go to the controller file (controller file should be active file) in VS and then run the application. It will open correct URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the **Start Action** for your ASP.NET Web Application is set to **Current Page**, which, in your case, is causing Visual Studio to launch a browser that navigates to the `/Mvc_Web_Project/Views/CreateNewUser/AddUser.cshtml` path.

To change this, one option is to go to the Project Properties window and change from **Current Page** to **Specific Page** and use an empty value, which will cause the browser to always navigate to the root of the application:

[image]

Here's a link to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164701.aspx) that explains the options in more detail.